# How to build data structure correctly on firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have quiz game and I want to add 1000 questions on firebase firestore and I have thousands of users in my game and every user has special id.

What is the best way to know if the user answered this question before or no?

Should I add user id inside every question who answered it or there is the another way?

I want build data structure logically for reduce consumptionmy read limit on firestore.

Comment: Storing user ID may have worked but there is a 1 MB limit on each Firestore document.

Comment: Add for each user a `collection` of answered questions. That ways every user only loads the data relevant for him. Depending on your code you could check each question on it's own for each user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two most common solutions I can quickly think of:

1. Create a single top-level collection `answers`, where you store all answers for all users. In that collection use the combination of UID and question ID to name each document, so that you can check if a document `/answers/$uid+$questionID` exists.
2. Create a top-level collection `users` in which each UID represents a user. Under each UID document create sub-collection answers, where you use the question ID to name the documents. Now you can check for each user if they answered a specific question, by checking `/users/$uid/answers/$questionId`.

Neither of these is pertinently better than the other, and they typically allow for similar use-cases. I'd usually pick the second structure simply because it results in a more natural distribution of the data, but it's s pretty small preference in practice.

Comment: Option two is good choice, But If I make this way I'll reach to 1 MB very soon because inside document another collection or I'm wrong?

Comment: Subcollections are not part of the parent document, so don't contribute towards that limit.